# Collapse or Expand a Layerset in Extendscript

Tags: javascript, photoshop, extendscript

I created a extendscript that automatically creates layersets for asset textures for a game.

After creating a layerset, the set is expanded by default. I want the layerset to be collapsed as shown in the picture below. I leave only the Diffuse layer to be expanded. The rest is closed. I've searched the reference by Adobe on how to do this but couldn't find anything. How do i collapse a layerset?

[image: The layersets as it should be: only Diffuse should be expanded]

Comment: Try the graphic design site ( http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ ).

Comment: I'm doing this through scripting. :)

Comment: I have never worked with extend script but I would think there is some event you can trigger in order to collapse/expand the layer set. I think Adobe support might be best to contact.

Answer (score 2):

As **Mr Mystery Guest** said, unfortunately you can't collapse a particular group, but you can collapse all the groups.

The link from the accepted answer is dead, so I will post here a solution:

```
var idcollapseAllGroupsEvent = stringIDToTypeID("collapseAllGroupsEvent");
var desc = new ActionDescriptor();
executeAction(idcollapseAllGroupsEvent, desc, DialogModes.NO);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this via scripting (I've looked into this before). There simply is no collapse (or equivalent) *layerSets* property to set!

However, what you can do is press CTRL (or Command on Mac) and click on the little arrow next to the group (in the layers window) - which will collapse all the groups for you.

There is a [work around solution](https://forums.adobe.com/message/7688137#7688137) : but you'll have to search for it